# Issue with Newton binomial coefficient in c++

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with my program for the Newton Binomial Coefficients. At first it printed negative numbers but changing the factorial function type to `unsigned long long` seemed to have fixed the problem with printing negative numbers. The program works for max `n = 20`, above it starts printing zeros, ones and twos. No idea how to fix that and hopefully someone can give me a hand.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned long long factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n*factorial(n - 1);
}

void Binom(int n ,int k) {
    unsigned long long factorialResult;
    if (k > n) {
        return;
    }
    factorialResult = factorial(n) /(factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));
    cout << factorialResult << " ";
    if (n >= k) {
        Binom(n, k + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Factorial gets very large very quickly. Can you think of a way to simplify the expression so the intermediate terms aren't so large? A lot of those factors cancel out.

Answer (score 7):

The factorials are typically very large, so you just have an integer overflow here. To fix this issue, you could implement any other algorithm of calculation `C(n, k)` not using factorials, for example:

```
unsigned long long C(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
    if (n == k || k == 0) {
        return 1; // There's exactly one way to select n or 0 objects out of n
    }
    return C(n - 1, k - 1) * n / k;
}
```

Here the following recurrent rule is used: `C(n, k) = C(n - 1, k - 1) * n / k`. It's very easy to prove since `C(n, k) = n! / (k! (n-k)!) = (n/k) * (n-1)! / ((k-1)!(n-1-k+1)!)`.

Comment: Won't this never end if `n!=k`?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, misprint. Fixed

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem and it can even accept a higher n in the input. Thanks for helping me out ^.^

Comment: @Dialecticus This is a tail recursion which will be optimized by compiler to non-recursive code. I think, recursive source code is better readable.

Comment: Not sure about this solution being a candidate for tail recursion. Recursive call must be the last operation for that, and can't move the call to after the `n / k` part because integer division is involved. A bit of refactoring is needed to avoid recursion. But I could be wrong :)

Comment: The refactoring is not too painful: `unsigned long long C_k_of_n(unsigned n, unsigned k)
{
    if (k > n/2) k = n-k;  // Make k as small as possible.
    unsigned long long result = 1uLL;
    for (unsigned num=n-k, denom = 0; denom < k;) {
        result *= ++num;
        result /= ++denom;
    }
    return result;
}`

Comment: @Martin Agree that the refactoring is very simple. But why you think non-recursive code is better in this case?

Comment: Because I don't think tail-call elimination will happen, and without it, that's an awful lot of recursion.

Comment: @Martin Without the overflow, recursion depth will be no more than several dozen levels. If we calculate cnk so much times that even this difference matters, a totally different approach should be used. And if we calculate it not so frequently, readability reasons matter.